# CentOS 7 - Postfix failing to start

Tags: centos, postfix, centos7

At the moment it's failing to start postfix. Here's the error I'm receiving:

```
warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
fatal: dictionary mail_dict: macro processing error
postfix.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Unit postfix.service entered failed state.
postfix.service failed.
```

Here's my main.cf (Only included the bit that's uncommented and been added to the file):

```
myhostname = mail.domain.net
mydomain = domain.net
myorigin = $mydomain
home_mailbox = mail/
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
inet_interfaces = localhost
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/server.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/server.crt
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

In the above code I've edited the mail.domain.net and domain.net in my local piece of code.

Postconf -n in full:

```
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mail.domain.net    mydomain = domain.net    myorigin = "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "    home_mailbox = mail/    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8    relay_domains =     inet_interfaces = all    inet_protocols = all    mydestination = "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "myhostname"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost."
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: ", localhost, "
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "mydomain"
postconf: fatal: dictionary mail_dict: macro processing error
```

Comment: Anything in logfile? Maybe some further details.

Comment: Which log file? When I do systemctl status postfix -l the error I receive is the same as above @deagh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one error on your main.cf: there should only be one line for `inet_interfaces` and `localhost` is not a valid value for ìnet_interfaces`

From http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_interfaces

> inet_interfaces (default: all)
>
> The network interface addresses that this mail system receives mail
>   on. Specify "all" to receive mail on all network interfaces (default),
>   and "loopback-only" to receive mail on loopback network interfaces
>   only (Postfix version 2.2 and later). The parameter also controls
>   delivery of mail to user@[ip.address].
>
> Note 1: you need to stop and
>   start Postfix when this parameter changes.
>
> Note 2: address information may be enclosed inside [], but this form
>   is not required here.
>
> When inet_interfaces specifies just one IPv4 and/or IPv6 address that
>   is not a loopback address, the Postfix SMTP client will use this
>   address as the IP source address for outbound mail. Support for IPv6
>   is available in Postfix version 2.2 and later.
>
> On a multi-homed firewall with separate Postfix instances listening on
>   the "inside" and "outside" interfaces, this can prevent each instance
>   from being able to reach remote SMTP servers on the "other side" of
>   the firewall. Setting smtp_bind_address to 0.0.0.0 avoids the
>   potential problem for IPv4, and setting smtp_bind_address6 to ::
>   solves the problem for IPv6.
>
> A better solution for multi-homed firewalls is to leave
>   `inet_interfaces` at the default value and instead use explicit IP
>   addresses in the master.cf SMTP server definitions. This preserves the
>   Postfix SMTP client's loop detection, by ensuring that each side of
>   the firewall knows that the other IP address is still the same host.
>   Setting `$inet_interfaces` to a single IPv4 and/or IPV6 address is
>   primarily useful with virtual hosting of domains on secondary IP
>   addresses, when each IP address serves a different domain (and has a
>   different $myhostname setting).
>
> See also the proxy_interfaces parameter, for network addresses that
>   are forwarded to Postfix by way of a proxy or address translator. 
>   Examples:
>
> ```
> inet_interfaces = all (DEFAULT)
> inet_interfaces = loopback-only (Postfix version 2.2 and later)
> inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1
> inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1, [::1] (Postfix version 2.2 and later)
> inet_interfaces = 192.168.1.2, 127.0.0.1
> ```

Comment: Thank you for that. I've removed one of the inet_interfaces and left the default one pointing to "all" (without the quotation marks). Although the exact same error is still presenting itself when running systemctl restart postfix -l. Would it help if I posted my master.cf or wouldn't that be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the Output of `postconf -n`? Maybe this helps in finding the error.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the output of postconf -n. It's quite long but it's repetitive.

Comment: Can you try and remove the first three lines of the config?

Comment: Weird. That worked. Where would postfix be picking up the hostname and domain from now? I've been more or less following this: https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-an-email-server-on-centos7/

Comment: Nevermind about the deleted comment, I fixed the issue. I removed one line from the inet_interfaces and left the other as all. I believe it's better to uncomment my_hostname and my_domain rather than adding a new line, which is made these errors disappear. Would you happen to know why the connection is refused when doing telnet mail.mydomain.net smtp

Comment: Maybe you News to Open the Ports in firewall.d. it Takes the Hostname from the system.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need `relayhost = your_mta`.

Comment: Why do you think that would help?

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately